# React white screen WSoD. Docker from tst to prd

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, nginx, k3s

I have an React application that was running well from a Docker image under a K3s cluster. The Dockerfile in tst was:

```
FROM node:alpine AS ui-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
ENV REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=prd     
ENV SERVER_ENVIRONMENT=prd    
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then, when I pass to a production style of deployment I use this Dockerfile

```
 FROM node:alpine AS ui-build
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
 ENV REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=prd
 ENV SERVER_ENVIRONMENT=prd
 RUN npm install
 COPY ./ ./
 RUN npm run build
 FROM nginx:alpine
 COPY --from=ui-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
 RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom.conf
 EXPOSE 80
 CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

where the nginx-custom.conf is this one:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

And when I load the page over the Internet I get the white screen of death but in the inspect page I get this:

```
main.07a0de9f.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.07a0de9f.js:1:1)
dom.js:1     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

the loaded code is like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
        <title>XYZ</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.07a0de9f.js"></script>
        <link href="./static/css/main.cb9cc68c.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't put the Kubernetes manifest files because I actually didn't change anything from tst to prd related to them and the page was loading well over the Internet.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.